# Blocking mounted devices from showing on Cinnamon desktop

Tags: linux-mint, mount, fstab, cinnamon

On Cinnamon 5.0.7 (Linux Mint 20.2), how do I prevent mounted devices, specifically device created in `fstab`, from showing up on the desktop and Nemo sidebar.

Until recently, this was the default behavior.  But after today's update/reboot, pretty much every mounted device is populating the desktop and  sidebar.

Majority of these are critical, background devices (e.g. filesystem root, /tmp, /home, ramdisks, etc.) that should never be unmounted.  They already have working mount points and need not be shown otherwise, **especially** with an "eject" button.

sample fstab line of some mounted device that show on desktop and Nemo:

```
UUID=###  /              btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
tmpfs     /mnt/ramdisk   tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nofail,size=500M  0 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable on the Desktop:

Right click the Desktop, click `Customize`, then click the hyperlink-looking `Desktop Settings` Button, and slide the `Mounted Drives` slider off.

To hide specific partitions from appearing in the user interface, you can open the `Disks` utility (`gnome-disks`). Then select the devices you want to hide and click the gear icon for that partition:
[image]

Next, select `Edit Mount Options...`
[image]

Next, uncheck `User Session Defaults`, and uncheck `Show in user interface`:

[image]

Once the system is rebooted, this device no longer showed up in the GUI on my VM

Comment: doesn't fix Nemo sidebar.  also, i want USB disks to populate desktop (as before).

Comment: Im working on the sidebar

Comment: You could modify the code to hardcode `show_eject_button` to false under all conditions https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/92126a823a9b85f73db7b0578895a2173ccde403/src/nemo-places-sidebar.c

Comment: I'm not interested in banning the "eject button".  I need it for removal device.  I just want to restore the default behavior before today's update, where only removal and network devices showed on desktop and sidebar.

Comment: I edited my question to give you a possible solution

Comment: Thanks.  This was not the problem. I looked and  `show in user interface` was already unchecked for the partitions.  But just did a second rebooted, and all the system mounts disappeared.    ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Nevertheless, your info was informative in general regarding mounted devices.

Answer (score 0):

On *Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon*, I add a `x-gvfs-hide` mount option for the partition I want to hide in *Disks* application, then the partition is hidden from *Nemo* and desktop immediately.

See [partitioning - How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu/)